# How many hashes for high probability of finding a collision (specific case)?

Tags: birthday-attack

Suppose Bob managed to obtain 220 different digests that were generated
by a hash function employed by a target system. The hash function outputs 8-byte
digest of a message. Bob now wants to find a message that hashes into 1 (one) of the
obtained digests. How many different messages should Bob approximately hash until
there is a good probability that a generated digest will match 1 of the obtained
digests?

My answer is $\sqrt{2^{64}}$ ($= 2^{32}$) messages for a probability of 0.5. Is this correct?

Comment: Lower, since you have multi-target

Comment: @kelalaka: your reasoning is right, but your "Lower" (than $2^{32}$) is incorrect. To the OP: your estimate is incorrect.

Comment: How did you come to your conclusion that it would be $\sqrt{2^{64}}$?

Comment: @AleksanderRas, since the hash function outputs 8-bytes digest of a message.

Comment: @fgrieu, any suggestion on how to approach this problem?

Comment: You are not exactly having a birthday problem. You need to find not an arbitrary collision, you need to find a hit into your set. You are looking for pre-images. I read you question, incorrectly!

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume that there are no prior collisions (two different messages that generate an identical hash) for the first $2^{64}$ messages.

If you want to find a message for **one** hash then you would have to try all these $2^{64}$ messages to reach the probability of 1 (100%). Since you mentioned *good probability* we can say that we would have to try half of that for a probability of 0.5 (50%). That means that we would have to try $2^{64} / \space 2$ possibilities which would be $2^{63}$.

Now you also already have a list of 220 hashes. That means that you can reduce it because we previously only calculated it for one hash, so the solution is:

$$\frac{2^{63}}{220} \approx 4.2 \times 10^{16}$$ for a probability of $0.5$ to find a message that hashes to one hash in your list.

Comment: @kelalaka, would appreciate on how to approach this problem. Thank you.

Comment: @alexkanderRas, so it is like solving for expected value?

Comment: @wongsimon What do you mean?

Comment: @aleskansdraRas, sorry my mistake. I thought it was similar to finding expected value as in probability. I am wrong, but now I understand your solution. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: You seem to assume that there are exactly $2^{64}$ possible messages; why?

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage The output of this hash is in this case 8 bytes, which would be 64 bits.

Comment: I was talking about inputs, not outputs.

Comment: There are of course more possible inputs, but we care about a collsion so I just took the minimum where a collision would be certain to appear (meaning that one of these $2^{64}$ inputs would have the same hash as one in the given list).

Comment: Suppose the messages are _unbounded_ in length.  Then the probability of finding at least one preimage after $2^{64}$ messages is _not_ 100%; rather, it is the CDF at $2^{64}$ of the negative binomial distribution for one success with a success probability of $220/2^{64}$.  Specifically, it is about $1 - (1 - 220/2^{64})^{2^{64}} \approx 1 - e^{-220}$.  Granted, that is very close to $1$; my point is that the reasoning is wrong unless the search is going through a space of exactly $2^{64}$ possible messages.

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage, would appreciate if you have any recommendation on introductory book or website for practice on problems of similar nature. Thank you.

Comment: @wongsimon Maybe try Willy Feller's introduction to probability theory?  This is a traditional balls & urns exercise.

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage, thanks for the recommendation.